# QPushButton Issues

Tags: qt, qt4, stylesheet

I am using the following code for create a button. It is working fine. but I got the yellow rectangle at the left corner.   Why? Please help me. Thanks in advance,

```
backButton = new QPushButton(tr("Back"));
         connect(backButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showSearchResultPage()));
         backButton->setStyleSheet(
             "background-image: url(/Users/aspire/IPhone Development/background_wood_Default.png);"
             "border-style: outset;"
             "border-width: 2px;"
             "border-radius: 10px;"
             "border-color: beige;"
             "font: bold 16px;"
             "color:black;"
             "min-width: 10em;"
             "min-height: 0.75em;"
            " margin: 0 1px 0 1px;"
             "color:rgb(255,246,143);"
             "padding: 6px;"
         );



QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
     layout->addWidget(backButton, 1, 0, 1, 1);
     layout->addWidget(detailView, 2, 0, 1, 1);
```

[image]

Comment: Just to double-check: You're sure that the rectangle isn't in your background image?

Comment: At high magnification, the yellow lines cross over the bottom border so I don't think it is in the background image. As jkerian suggests, the problem is elsewhere :) I would guess another widget is parented to the button or maybe the parent of the button has a stylesheet (without selectors) that is being inherited by the button.

Comment: THanks.If I used the stylesheet for button then only i got the rectangle. If I use the std button style then I am not getting the issue. Please help me.. I used the following code. secondclsss::secondclsss(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) { QPushButton *first = new QPushButton("first"); first->setStyleSheet( "background-color:black;" ); QGridLayout *d = new QGridLayout(); d->addWidget(frist,0,0,1,1); setLayout(d); connect(first,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(first())); } void secondclsss:: first() { this->hide(); } –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the problem is not in the code you posted (unless, as cjhuitt mentions, it's in the background image). I snagged a simple background png off of google and tried the following python:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtGui.QWidget()

button = QtGui.QPushButton("Back")

button.setStyleSheet(
        "background-image: url(wood.png);"
        "border-style: outset;"
        "border-width: 2px;"
        "border-radius: 10px;"
        "border-color: beige;"
        "font: bold 16px;"
        "color: black;"
        "min-width: 10em;"
        "min-height: 0.75em;"
        "margin: 0 1px 0 1px;"
        "color:rgb(255,245,143);"
        "padding: 6px;"
        )

grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(widget)
grid.addWidget(button,1,0,1,1)

widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It produces the button without the odd little yellow box you're showing there.

Comment: Thanks.If I used the stylesheet for button then only i got the rectangle. If I use the std button style then I am not getting the issue. Please help me..  I used the following code.                 secondclsss::secondclsss(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QPushButton *first = new QPushButton("first");
    first->setStyleSheet(
         "background-color:black;"

    );
    QGridLayout *d = new QGridLayout();

    d->addWidget(frist,0,0,1,1);
    setLayout(d);
    connect(first,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(first()));
}

void secondclsss:: first()
{
    this->hide();
}

Comment: Python?? Thats cheating! ;)